# IntelliJ autocompletion and docker

Tags: python, intellij-idea, docker

I have on my system IntelliJ and Docker with a container to run my project. Is there a way to tell IntelliJ to use the container to do auto completion (and all great modern ide features)?

This is currently what I see in my IDE:

[image]

I can of course run my project using docker successfully.

Comment: Maybe an example what you try to do would help to understand the question.

Comment: @Henry I have edited the question.

Comment: This does not look like Java; which language is it?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-docker.html